# Traditional drinks for celebrating the Feast of the Epiphany?

Tags: history, local, drinking, wine, holidays

Most places celebrate the [Feast of the Epiphany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(holiday)) on January 6.

Are there any local, traditional drinks that exist that people have as a way celebrating this feast in a local and traditional manner?

Update: I am limiting this question to wines.

Comment: Are you talking mixed drinks or alcohol in general? Otherwise, I think it is almost always wine...

Comment: @ Steve S. Limited to wines.

Comment: All I can say is that wine is widespread through the Eastern Orthodox regions. I don't think there is any special wines they drink. It might depend on where you are. Probably red wine since it's used in rituals to replace the "blood of Christ". I dated a woman who was Eastern Orthodoxed from Slovenia originally and I don't think they cared as long as it was decent red wine.

Comment: Eggnog comes to mind.?

Comment: It suddenly occurred to me by way of a  striking realization  that Epiphany vineyards must be turning water into wine.

Answer (score 3):

According to the wiki that you linked:

> The earliest reference to Epiphany as a Christian feast was in A.D. 361, by Ammianus Marcellinus.

So, it would be pertinent to drink wines made from [Italian grapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_wine#Italian_grape_varieties) since the feast was held within the time of the Roman Empire.

More particularly, you might pick a grape variety from [a list of ancient grapes](http://www.unrv.com/economy/wine-chart.php) from which the Romans, themselves, would have made wine.

Not that it's entirely pertinent to the Feast of Epiphany, but it is apt to say here that, you might purchase your wine here: https://www.epiphanywineco.com/ :)

As far as my quick and limited research has gone, there really isn't an 'official' wine of the feast - not really a Christian concept to have "official alcoholic beverages," imho.

As far as local traditions, the wiki you linked covers the traditions of the feast internationally but again, alcohol consumption doesn't really ever seem to be the focus...

Also, let's not forget that the Roman's would have had beer at this feast...

Answer (score 0):

**Traditional drinks for celebrating the Feast of the Epiphany?**

It is wine you want perhaps try a [**Magi Wine**](https://www.vivino.com/magi-balthazar-gimblett-road-hawkes-bay-cabernet-sauvignon-merlot-cabernet-franc/w/2215924?cart_item_source=referrer-www.google.ca)

[image: Balthazar Cabernet Sauvignon Merlot Cabernet]

**Balthazar** says it all!